# Form not submitting data after validation

Tags: javascript

long time reader first time poster. I am having an issue with a form. It has email validator with JavaScript and once the validation is correct it supposedly has to submit the data but this doesn't happen. If I run the form without the validation the data goes through without a problem but with the validation I have a success message and then no data.

```js
function ValidateEmail(email)
{
    var mailformat = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
    if(!email.match(mailformat))
    {
        alert("valid email is required");
        return false;
    }else{
        document.querySelector('form').submit();
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.parent.location = "https://www.xxxs.com/";           
        }, 3000);
    }
    
}

window.onload= function(){
 document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').addEventListener("click", 
    function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var email = document.querySelector('input[name^="Email"]').value;
        ValidateEmail(email);
    }); 
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided the markup to go along with it, so I can only speculate that there's a problem with the markup.

I also have no idea why you've added this.

```js
setTimeout(function(){
    window.parent.location = "https://www.xxxs.com/";           
}, 3000);
```

Apart from this, it works pretty well for my [sandbox](https://jsfiddle.net/91uq3nLo/).

PS: I can't comment yet due to reputation, but @Kayden van Rijn might be interested in

```js
/* Links that start with "https" and end in ".org" */
a[href^="https"][href$=".org"] {
  color: green;
}
```

from [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: Oh wow that's cool, I had no idea that existed! Does this work for any tag with built-in attributes?